# fetch product from more than one category

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to fetch product from more than one category and I am using

```
 $category_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%'.$searchstring.'%'))
              ->load();

 foreach ($category_collection as $category) {
    $ids[] = $category->getId();
 }

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => $ids)))
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setPageSize(5);
```

but it shows error `Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "2" already exist`

please help me to get distinct collection.

Comment: You are filtering category_id by providing product ids.

Comment: No I filtering product from category id array

Comment: Hmm you seem to have updated the code.

Comment: only I used different naming convention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get by code:-

```
 // Code to Search Product by $searchstring and get Product IDs
    $category_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' => '%' . $searchstring . '%'))
            ->load();

    foreach ($category_collection as $category) {
        $category_id = $category->getId();
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->addCategoryFilter($category); //category filter
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1); //only enabled product
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //add product attribute to be fetched        
        $collection->addStoreFilter();
        foreach ($collection as $_product):
            $ids[] = $_product->getId();
        endforeach;
    }
    $ids = array_unique($ids);
    $html = '';
    foreach ($ids as $_ids):
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_ids);
        $html .= '<img name="'.$product->getPrice().'" alt="'.$product->getName().'" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="' . $product->getId() . '" class="ui-widget-content ui-draggable" src="' .  $product->getImageUrl() . '" width="50px" height="50px" />';
    endforeach;
    echo $html;

$ids will return unique id and in foreach we can load product.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a group by statement. You get duplicate products because you have the same product in multiple categories and your code retrieves them twice (at least) and a collection does not support items with the same id.

So at the end of your code add this

```
$collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

or

```
$collection->getSelect()->group('main_table.entity_id');
```

I don't remember exactly what is the table alias.